# GSSAPI Authentication Error: "An invalid name was supplied" (FQDN, FREEIPA)

Tags: 18.04, openssh

When trying to connect to a FreeIPA client via SSH using GSSAPI it produces the error: **An invalid name was supplied**. The name/key used is: **"Host/mail@"** which shows something has gone wrong server-side, but I'm not sure where to debug/check for the reason it's not putting in the `fqdn` or `realm` in the provided key.

**Reference:**

Client: MacOS Mojave

Server: Ubuntu 18.04

Also, the FreeIPA server connects with GSSAPI to the client with no problem.